# ANY ng command will fail when trying angular due to invalid character error in ng file

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

The \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js file cannot be opened and it gives an error whenever I try to use an ng command anywhere, be it in an angular project or elsewhere.

The error is as follows:
Script: (my username)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js
Line: 1
Character: 1
Error: Invalid Character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Compilationerror Microsoft Jscript

What I have tried:

using ng commands in different project -- same error
reinstall npm, angular, removing the node modules in all combinations
Setting the angular path in the environment variables

What happened before:
ng command was missing possibly due to stuff related to python install. This error is replaced with my current problem when reinstall is done.

I have reinstalled everything to the fullest extent but the problem keeps persisting.
I can use my angular project by running 'npm run ng serve' and that weirdly works.

Does anyone have ANY idea what might cause this problem

EDIT:
I have somehow managed to resolve the problem but I have no clear answer what was the cause of it all. I did reinstall nodeJS on my computer which MIGHT have been broken during another project.

Comment: I am having this issue too. Do you happen to have NVM installed? https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows I do, and I wonder if it's messing with things

Comment: I don't think I have nvm I haven't heard of it before and have therefore never knowingly used it. I would certainly not have it installed in the period between it working and not working. I think my problems might stem from doing python things.

Comment: I have resolved the problem but I honestly cannot tell what finally did the trick, one thing I haven't seen mentioned yet was a fresh reinstall of nodeJS (as in the programm itself) with a combination of all suggestion somehow I got it working again so a thanks to all and I will set it as resolved.

Answer (score 16):

Remove the user environment variable

```
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin
```

It worked for me after losing a day of life looking for a solution

Comment: this work for me, thanks.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me.

Comment: @robindewitte Try reopening the terminal

Comment: Tried that several times, no result

Comment: @robindewitte Could you solve it?

Comment: reopening a different terminal worked for me

Comment: no result. not working

Comment: DId you remove the first line which is  #!/usr/bin/env node?

Comment: @Nakres  you have to go to your environment variables and delete the variable

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error occured because of permissions on windows. Try to run cmd as Administrator.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is setting this path:

set path=%PATH%;C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 1):

Deleting and reinstalling node.js did not fix it. The issues started when I installed latest CLI which is 13.

I removed npm folder from C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming then I installed the previous version

npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.0

I do not get the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to set the path of npm

$ npm config get prefix

## make sure path matches with npm config get prefix

export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH

in windows you can set by advance system settings -> Environment variable -> set path.

Restart you system then do this -

$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

## get package version

$ ng version

## create workspace

$ ng new my-project

## run the application

$ cd my-project

$ ng serve

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the package and reinstall it:

$ npm rm -g @angular/cli@latest

$ npm clean cache

$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

*MOST IMPORTANT*

Restart your machine.
Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error and wanted to share some insights on how I resolved it.

### Error Details-

### (my username)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js
Line: 1 Character: 1
Error: Invalid Character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Compilation error Microsoft Jscript

Probable Cause-

> When you try to install @angular/cli globally, there seems to be an issue with the build in ng.js file.
> ***`[npm install -g @angular/cli]`***

Resolution-

> Uninstall the globally installed angular/cli
> ***`[npm uninstall -g @angular/cli]`***

> Clear npm Cache -
> ***`npm cache clean --force`***

> Install @angular/cli locally and it seems to be working fine.
> ***`[npm install @angular/cli]`***

> Also, after installation make sure you add the path to your environment variable.

Example- **"C:\Users{user_name}\node_modules.bin"**

It will be installed in the path where you'll run the installation for angular/cli